# is the device mounted correctly on android

Tags: android, c++, usbserial

I have a USB device based on USB-RS232 chips.When I plug it in the USB on android it is mounted to /dev/bus/usb/xxx/xxx.
but I can not write this device by bash command or write() in C++.I expect to write it like writing a serial device.Is this device mounted correctly?what should I do for this?